# for loop jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

Why is it that if I give a variable a "0", then in the html the number is "10"? I'm using jQuery and JavaScript both, but as you can see the number in the middle is "10" after I reload the page. It's always "10" and not changing.

I'm trying so that that purple square goes in circles 10 times and I want the middle number to change every round up by one. How can I achieve that?

```js
let calc = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  $('#animate').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      top: '350px'
    });
    $(this).animate({
      left: '350px'
    });
    $(this).animate({
      top: '0px'
    });
    $(this).animate({
      left: '0px'
    });
  });
  document.getElementById("szam").innerHTML = calc;
  calc++;
}
```

```css
#container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#animate {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#szam {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 170px;
  font-size: 72px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-
    2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="animate">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <h1 id="szam">0</h1>
</div>
```

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What do you think, what would `calc++` do within the for loop? Ah, wait! You expect to see numbers from 0 to 10?

Comment: Why do you expect it to change? Naked eyes can not see the changes made by for-loop :D

Comment: What exactly are you hoping for the outcome to be? I just can't even tell what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for helping guys....I'm learning programming sorry i have to start somewhere

Comment: I'm trying so that that purple square goes in circles 10 times and I want the middle number to change every round up by one.

Comment: @void There's nothing in the world which could see the change, because the html is rendered only after the script has been executed, at that time there's only 10 left to show.

Comment: you don't see that because a for-loop is processed too many fast to you actually see that, when the page loads, the for already finished and then the number is already 10

Comment: And so Is there any way to solve this? so it works?

Comment: maybe you are looking for a `setInterval()`, that is a function to made something every defined time... `setInterval(function()..., 2000);`

Comment: @Marton - it's ok to be learning. Ignore anyone who tries to make you feel stupid. They were once that way too. What you are experiencing is not that unusual. The display is not changing because of two things - the for loop runs all the way through very very fast, and Javascript doesn't update the display every time it performs an operation. It does all it's calculations for one 'cycle' and then updates the screen. What you need to do is slow things down. You can do that with a timeout.

Comment: @MártonGergő I suggest you to read and learn more, you cannot "Fix" that, it's not an error, it is the expected behavior of a for-loop, it's not to be visible, it is to be processed

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp  and here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp may help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop runs relatively quickly, but the animations are queued by default. This means that the code iterates `i` from 0 to 10 and queues each animation, but displays 10 almost immediately because the loop happens so fast. On the other hand, each animation waits for the previous animation to finish before it starts. So the animation takes much more time to complete than the loop itself.

To demonstrate with the code below, notice that the "Loop is done" message seems to appear as soon as the trigger is clicked.

One solution is to use the `complete` callback of jQuery's [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to advance the counter when each cycle is complete.

> **complete**
> Type: Function()
> A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.
>
> .animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )

```js
var calc = 0;
var elm = document.getElementById("szam");

function advance() {
  calc++;
  elm.innerHTML = calc;
}

$('#animate').click(function() {

  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  
    $(this).animate({
      top: '150px'
    }).animate({
      left: '150px'
    }).animate({
      top: '0'
    }).animate({
      left: '0'
    }, advance);
    
  }

  console.log('Loop is done.');

});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#animate {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#szam {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 85px;
  font-size: 72px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-
    2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="animate">
    <p>CLICK</p>
  </div>
  <h1 id="szam">0</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Finally thank you a good answer. I'm sorry if it was a poor/ bad question but I'm just learning/trying and I couldn't figure this out. So sorry but thank you for the answer.